# Converting react native project into expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to do the conversion of my **react-native** project into **Expo** with the command line '**exp convert**'. 
`And I follow the following steps:`

> 1. npm install -g exp
> 2. then I started 'exp convert'

The problem is that execution blocks at this level in picture bellow . so I could not complete the conversion process Is there any one who can help me to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Even this is an old question but still people are looking for better answer.
Here is what they(Expo people) officially say at the moment(2019-March)

> Right now, the easiest way to do this is to use expo init (with Expo CLI) to make a new project, and then copy over all your JavaScript source code from your existing project, and then yarn adding the library dependencies you have.

...

> N.B. We used to maintain a tool exp convert but it is not currently working or maintained so the above method is the best way to get an existing React Native project working on Expo

You will find more details in this link
- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq/#how-do-i-get-my-existing-react

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about that `exp convert` command, but there are a few steps you can follow (and a few things to keep in mind), such as:

- the RN project shouldn't have any native modules
- make sure all dependencies are installed properly - including Expo as a project dependency `npm install --save expo`
- properly specify the `app.json` properties for Expo [such as name, slug name and SDK version] in the directory with the JS code
- modify the entry file [like `index.js`]
- create the `exp.json` file and also update the React/React Native versions as to what's required by Expo

More detailed info here: https://github.com/expo/xde#converting-an-existing-project-to-work-with-expo